# How Do I resize a partition?

Tags: linux, partition, mdadm

I have the following FIle system setup currently. I need as much room as i can get in ./home.

```
 root@Jm2:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1         20G  7.6G   11G  42% /
udev             32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  640K  6.3G   1% /run
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             32G  8.0K   32G   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md2        127G   98G   24G  81% /home
```

So things like /run/shm can be made alot smaller if I get the option.

How would I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: `/run/shm` is not a partition.

Answer (score 1):

`/run/shm` can be resized but it won't help as it's a virtual filesystem, a ramdisk.

If you want to resize `/home` you have to check the underlying drives of the `/dev/md2` raid (resize, replace or add additional drives to that raid).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this from the disk the system is installed to, it should raise an error "device is busy", but you can boot a live disk and change things around.

```
parted
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html for more information on how to use parted.